# Save a directory list to a text file

Tags: windows, list, batch-file, directory, cmd

I'm trying to list the content of two directories on my HD and put it in a file.

For the moment I have this which list all the directories and contents :

```
echo off
for /r %%a in (*) do echo %%a >> file.txt
```

How can I look into a specific folder like `Pictures` for example ?

Here is the tree :

```
> Dir1
> Dir2
> Pictures
> file.bat
```

Comment: `dir c:\pictures >> file.txt ?` if you want to look in subdirs use `dir /r c:\pictures`. If you want to see the names only use `dir /b`. See `dir /?` for all options

Comment: Yeah great ! But the `/r` is not working :/

Comment: @kayasax Your previous comment contains errors.  /r is for displaying alternate data streams.

Comment: Yep i was thinking about /recursive in  powershell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
for /r "pictures" %%a in (*) do echo %%~nxa
```

Comment: I want to put it in a file

Comment: Thanks it's working ! Is there a way to encode special chars ? `éèà`

Comment: I have this which give me the full path : `for /r "Pictures" %%a in (*) do echo "%%a">> pic.txt`, how can I escape backslashes ?

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /b /s /a-d "c:\pictures" >file.txt
```